# Why does Jest pass test if function is declared asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, jestjs

This passes

```
test('test_test', async () => {
  try {
    const received = true;
    const expected = false;
    expect(received).toBe(expected);
  } catch (err) {
    return err
  }
});
```

This fails as it should

```
test('test_test', () => {
  try {
    const received = true;
    const expected = false;
    expect(received).toBe(expected);
  } catch (err) {
    return err
  }
});
```

I have a function using async and await and this is the reason the test will not fail so I'm trying to understand how to make the top fail as it should.

Comment: Why are the `try` and `catch` there at all? If you remove them the test fails just fine, `async` or not.

Comment: I'm using it with CircleCi and it said to use try catches where using async await

Comment: Could you link that advice? I'd be more inclined to follow Jest's own guidance: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async; you only need to catch the error if you're trying to test that the code you're testing *throws an error correctly*.

Comment: Just ran some test code as is and CircleCi didn't complain. You are right its the try catch. 

Here's the Circle's message for clarity  `(node:727) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)`

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe suggested to remove `try`/`catch` it behaves as expected now and fails.